# What's the use of using a lambda function to call a function?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, keyword-argument

So, as the title suggest, I don't know what's the use of using a lambda function to call another function, especially when putting that lambda function as a keyword argument in a widget such as a button.

```py
def multiply(x,y):
    print(x*y)

window = Tk()

x = 1
y = 1
button = Button(window, text='button' command= lambda x=x, y=y : multiply(x,y))
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I've been trying to play with it myself. I tried not to use a lambda function to call another function but it's not working as I expected it to be.

Comment: Show sample code of what you tried as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Because if you said `command=multiply`, it doesn't get called with any parameters.  Using `lambda` lets you customize the call for each widget, because the `lambda` "captures" the values of `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is that when you click on your button, your function `multiply` gets called with the argument "x" and "y"

So achieve this, you need to create a pointer to the function multiply with the right argument, which you can achieve using a lambda expression.

if you were to do `button = Button(window, text='button' command= multiply(x,y))`

you are not assigning a pointer to a function to the command argument, but instead directly calling `multiply(x,y)`

you can try this yourself by modify your code

Let's see an example

```
def print_value(i):
    print(i)


lambda_list = []
normal_list = []

for i in range(0,4):
    normal_list.append(print_value(i))
```

if you do this, you'll see that `0,1,2,3` gets printed, because I'm calling the function `print_value`

Now if I do this :

```
def print_value(i):
    print(i)


lambda_list = []
normal_list = []

for i in range(0,4):
    lambda_list.append(lambda x=i : print_value(x))
```

Nothing gets printed, because I added pointer to the function inside my list through lambda function, and not directly called the function

but now if I continue my example by doing this

```
for lambda_func in lambda_list:
    lambda_func()
```

`0,1,2,3` gets printed because I'm now calling my function pointer with the argument I gave to it (through lambda x=i)

now last example

If I were to do

```
lambda_list = []

for i in range(0,4):
    lambda_list.append(lambda: print_value(i))


for lambda_func in lambda_list:
    lambda_func()
```

What would be the result? answer : 3 3 3 3

Because when you do `lambda x=i : print_value(x)` you are capturing the current value of " `i` " , but when you do `lambda: print_value(i)`, it always references the same "i" (the one of the for loop), ence why you may need to do
`lambda x=x, y=y : multiply(x,y)` in your case instead of `lambda: multiply(x,y)`

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's super clear.